# How can i add two or more text box on same row. In magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks

I want to add two textboxes on single row, how can i achieve this using block classes in magento 2. I want this on admin side.

[image]

Here is the code

```
          $fieldset->addField(
            'option_1',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'option_1',
                'label' => __('Option 1'),
                'class' => 'txt-type',
                'title' => __('Option'),
                'required' => true,
                'maxlength' => '50',
                'container_id' => 'some_row'
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'option_2',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'option_2',
                'label' => __('Option 2'),
                'class' => 'txt-type',
                'title' => __('Option'),
                'required' => true,
                'note' => '',
                'container_id' => 'some_row'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Are you using UI component?

Comment: No block classes

Comment: @PrincePatel do you have any solution for UI component ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add two text boxes on the same line you have to wrap your fields in a group container, if you are planning to use UI component just add this code snippet :

```
<container name="option_group">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">group</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</item>
                <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="option_1">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">txt-type</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">240</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">option_2</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">txt-type</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">240</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_2</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </container>
```

To achieve the same result with $fieldset->addField i think this should be doable with some tweaking by using the renderer.

Here is a link that may help you : 
https://belvg.com/blog/renderer-in-magento-2-0.html